# Spring Foreign key infinity loop

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I have a table User that had a Foreign key Store to reference the store of the User.

Secondly, I have a table Store that had a foreign key responsable that is in fact a User Id.

In my `Spring` application , I made the Mapping Object Relation, and i Create a class model with `@ManyTOone` for Store in my User Class and for User in my store Class.

I create the Repository and a `REstController`.

When i tried a `findOne` Method in my UserRepository, I have a infinity Loop, because it is loading the STore in the User and so the User in the Store and so the Store in the User and so ....

What is the best practice to avoid that situation.

Thanks

Comment: A circular dependency like that doesn't cause an infinite loop. Show your code.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you render it out directly, you have to set one relation to the Managed Reference with the annotation

@JsonManagedReference for example at your OneToMany declaration

and the

@JsonBackReference annotation on the @ManyToOne declaration.

If you don't do this, you run into this infinity loop.

There are other possibilities too look at this:

http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at your [fetch type](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/FetchType.html) attribute: `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`. If you have `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToMany` annotations in both of your entities, one of them should use lazy fetch type to avoid an infinite loop. For example:

```
@Entity(name = "ATTRIBUTE")
public class Attribute {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CONFIG_ID")
    private Config config;
    ...
}

@Entity(name = "CONFIG")
public class Config {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "config", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Attribute> attributes;
    ...
}
```

Notice that default fetch type is eager.

Comment: These will effect that the entity will not deliver the related child objects... this is not what he  wants to do. With your solution you have to call the repository two times. First time for the config and the second time for the attributes to deliver both...

Comment: Yes, it is true, but only for Attribute entity: we have to explicitly load Config from it. But Config entity loads all related attributes eagerly.